# SQL Stored Procs Null Parameters for a search of item

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a SQL stored procedure that will be used for the search of an item. I am allowing the user to search by item code or UPC. Thus, I need to be able to allow my parameters to be null. I think I'm close, however, when I execute this stored procedure it returns too many results when I am expecting only one.

Here's what I have:

```
  @itm_ItemCode int,
  @itm_UPC varchar(11)

SELECT 
     ITEM_CODE as itm_itemcode 
    ,UPC_CODE as itm_upc
    ,[DESCRIPTION] as itm_description
    ,BASE_PRICE as itm_regularcost

FROM ITEM_TABLE 
    where (ITEM_CODE = @itm_ItemCode or @itm_ItemCode IS NULL) 
          OR (UPC_CODE = @itm_UPC or @itm_UPC IS NULL)
```

Here are a few examples of what I have for my EXEC statement when I try to test my stored procedure: (Is this how I'm suppose to write my EXEC statements?

```
EXEC stp_ItemSearch null, 71591010583
EXEC stp_ItemSearch 300, null
```

Thank you for your help!

P.S. I'm using SQL Server Manager

Comment: Perhaps the OR outside the () needs to be an `and`.  Using ITEM_CODE = 'xyz' AND @itm_UPC is NULL as an example...  using OR then the ITEM_CODE = 'xyz' would return AND all itm_UPCs that are NULL would also return.  OR means either can be true for it to return a record.  And means both need to be true for it to return a record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `and`, not `or`

```
 where (ITEM_CODE = @itm_ItemCode or @itm_ItemCode IS NULL) 
      AND (UPC_CODE = @itm_UPC or @itm_UPC IS NULL)
```

Both of your examples have one parameter as `null`, so will return all rows.

If `Item_code` and `upc_code` are not nullable, then your code can be shortened to

```
where (ITEM_CODE = ISNULL(@itm_ItemCode,ITEM_CODE ))
      AND (UPC_CODE = ISNULL(@itm_UPC,UPC_CODE ))
```

Comment: Hi there Podiluska!! Oh my how embarrassing of me to miss something that simple!! Thank you so much for your help!! I appreciate it!!